# Rust compile error - cannot infer type for type parameter

Tags: rust

I am trying to write  a simple cache implementation in rust.

The general idea is to fetch serialized object from remote location, deserialize it, and save it the deserialized object in the local cache. I want to use the `DeserializeOwned` trait in the cache because the cached object lifetime is longer than the raw data.

I started with the following code:

```
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::collections::HashMap; 

    
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Demo{
    s: u32
}

pub struct Cache<T : DeserializeOwned> {
    cache: HashMap<String , T>, 
}

impl<T: DeserializeOwned> Cache<T> {
    pub fn new<K :DeserializeOwned>() -> Cache<K> {
        let cache  = HashMap::new(); 
        
        Cache {
            cache, 
        }

    }
}

fn main() {
    let cache = Cache::new::<Demo>(); 
}
```

and got the following error :

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:96:17
   |
84 |     pub fn new<K :DeserializeOwned>() -> Cache<K> {
   |                   ---------------- required by this bound in `Cache::<T>::new`
...
96 |     let cache = Cache::new::<Demo>(); 
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T`
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: DeserializeOwned`
```

But if i try to implement `DeserializeOwned` for `Demo` object the compiler complains about conflicting about conflicting implementation.

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm voting "not reproducible" because it's very unlikely that a future asker with the same problem will be able to find this question by searching, and it's hard to imagine editing the question to be more findable without either making it so broad as to be virtually meaningless, or so narrow that you can only find it by already knowing the answer, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Well I found it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two separate generic type parameters for `Cache::new`, and the fully qualified syntax with your example would be `Cache::<Demo>::new::<Demo>()`. This is probably not what you intended, since the type parameter on `Cache` itself is completely unused in `Cache::new`. Instead, I'd remove the type parameter from the function and instead use the existing type parameter from `Cache`, like so:

```
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::collections::HashMap; 

    
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Demo{
    s: u32
}

pub struct Cache<T : DeserializeOwned> {
    cache: HashMap<String , T>, 
}

impl<T: DeserializeOwned> Cache<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Cache<T> {
        let cache  = HashMap::new(); 
        
        Cache {
            cache, 
        }

    }
}

fn main() {
    let cache = Cache::<Demo>::new(); 
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10e182606998203d72b8df6b622805c0)

Comment: thanks :). i believe it's trivial i am new with Generic ..